# Remove Certain Shipping method on estimate and checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, shipping-methods

- I want to remove Some of shipping method on both estimate and
  checkout page.
- If parameter in quote `remove_all` to `1` then remove all method which
  are available and set only one which i have created.
- if `remove_all` is `0` then remove just my custom shipping method keep
  which all are available

I think there should be an observer event when all shipping methods are render and i can remove from there.

Comment: Yes, we know your requirements :)  but what you tried to achieve this? or you are looking for a direct solution from someone?

Comment: i'm trying after method aftercollectRates but nothing help

Comment: So please mentioned what you tried far so someone can understand :)

Comment: but i dont think it helps may be i dont know any observer should be there

Answer (score 2):

You can use next plugin for your purpose:

```
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result">
    <plugin name="your_plugin_name_update_rate_result"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ShippingRateResultAppend"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false" />
</type>
```

code will be like this one, but with own validation:

```
/**
 * Disable the marked shipping rates. 
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $subject
 * @param array $result
 * @return array
 */
public function afterGetAllRates($subject, $result)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->getQuote(); // method must be defined in your class; you can get an actual quote from a session;
    if (!$quote) {
        // exception?
    }
    $removeAll                = (int)$quote->getRemoveAll();
    $customShippingMethodCode = 'custom_methodcode'; // static

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method[] $result */
    /**
     * @var int $key
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $rate
     */
    foreach ($result as $key => $rate) {
        $methodCode = $rate->getCarrier() . '_' . $rate->getMethod();
        if ($removeAll && $methodCode !== $customShippingMethodCode) {
            unset($result[$key]);
        } elseif (!$removeAll && $methodCode === $customShippingMethodCode) {
            unset($result[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```